# Microsoft Bing maps WPF - Heat Map

Tags: c#, wpf, bing-maps, heatmap

I am making an application that load points on a map that uses the Microsoft library of BingMaps (WPF desktop)

I'm needing the points that are loaded on the map is displayed as a heat map, but the control does not have that functionality.

Anyone know of a library which can be used with heat maps?

Thank you !!

PS: I've got some libraries, but they work for web applications and desktop need. For example:

http://alastaira.wordpress.com/2011/02/23/heat-mapping-crime-data-with-bing-maps-and-html5-canvas/

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Heat-Maps-in-Windows-Store-5e8982d9

Answer (score 1):

I actually created heat maps for the WPF map control earlier this year and made it available as part of this library: http://mapstoolbox.codeplex.com/

It was working great until I did a windows update yesterday. I haven't had a chance to debug yet but will hopefully have a chance tomorrow. There is a good chance it will work for you as I'm also messing around with a few other things on my side which might of broke my local copy.